# List spelling errors in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to know if there's a way to list all spelling errors in microsoft word. In the list should appear the link to the error so one can directly go to the error and correct it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply press `F7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking [image] on the Review tab of the Ribbon bar, or pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> will open a panel to the right. This panel lists the spelling mistakes, and navigates you to the spelling error in the document when clicked.

[image]

Comment: `F7` is the hotkey shortcut

Comment: Thanks @JW0914, answer updated.